# Reverted downvotes appear to be cached

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, down-votes, caching

I have seen this a number of times now:

- I answer a question - my answer gets downvoted.
- Downvoter reverts the downvote.
- The page still shows the downvote, even though the rep and rep audit show there was no downvote.

This is the latest occurrence for me:

[Tool for generating POCO/DTO from database (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836381/tool-for-generating-poco-dto-from-database-sql-server/4836402#4836402)

At the moment, there is one upvote and one downvote (reverted). My rep and audit tell me there the downvote shouldn't be there anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is totally correct (and has nothing to do with caching).

Someone has flagged your answer as spam. A spam flag comes with a side dish of free downvote by the community user. This downvote reflects on the post score, but not the reputation (it's only when enough users flag the post for it to be deleted that there is a reputation penalty to the poster).

Now, whether the spam flag was valid is a totally different thing – I think it wasn't, and have hence invalidated it, and you'll see there's no downvote on the post anymore.